# Ошибка при добавлении в простой проект библиотек reac, react-dom, babel

Tags: html, css, create-react-app

Если добавить эти библиотеки, то появляется ошибка, если добавить к проекту пустой js-файл. Путь к js-файлу прописан верно, в папке с html файлом он присутствует. Если убрать строку src="areact.js", то программа прекрасно запускается. Если добавить js-код в элемент script в конце файла, то тоже всё работает. Вот код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

     <div id = "app"></div>
      

    <script type="text/babel" src="areact.js">

       


    </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что за ошибка то?

Comment: : ccess to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/Jim/Desktop/HTML/areact/areact.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.

Comment: Проблема у вас в том, как вы запускаете страничку. Вы запускаете ее локально, о чем говорит протокол `file://` ну и собственно ошибка. Поднимите локальный сервер и там запустите ваш "сайт"